# How to use variables with loop in :lt jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I'm trying to parse an xml, and then take put the values as per the xml into 4 divs sequentially. In these divs, first value to be changed is the `<a href>` second is inside the anchor `<img src>` and third is also inside the anchor `<h2>TITLE</h2>`.

I was successful in changing the values via :first for the first of the appearing divs... Then I tried looking for how to change content for remaining 3 divs.. My current code is based on only 3 divs only for the demo purpose...

My code is as follows:

## HTML

```
<div class="h"> <a class="anchor" data-prd_id="1a" href="#">
<div class="image"> <img class="image-first" src="image_" alt="">
<div class="meta"> 
<h2 class="title">Dynamically_loaded</h2> 
<span class="arrow"></span> </div> 
</div>                       
</a> </div>


<div class="h"> <a class="anchor" data-prd_id="1b" href="#">
<div class="image"> <img class="image-first" src="image_" alt="">
<div class="meta"> 
<h2 class="title">Dynamically_loaded</h2> 
<span class="arrow"></span> </div> 
</div>                       
</a> </div>


<div class="h"> <a class="anchor" data-prd_id="2a" href="#">
<div class="image"> <img class="image" src="image_" alt="">
<div class="meta"> 
<h2 class="title">Dynamically_loaded</h2> 
<span class="arrow"></span> </div> 
</div>                       
</a> </div>
```

## JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
window.onload = function()
    {   
    function item_code(j){
      fValue =  $('a.anchor:lt(' + j + ')').attr("data-prd_id");
    return fValue; 
    }

 $.ajax({
    url: 'demo_xml_parser.xml', // name of file you want to parse
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function parse(xmlResponse){


 $(xmlResponse).find("item").each(function() {
  var pr_id = $(this).find("p_id").text();

  for (int i=1;i<=3;i++;){
  var id_selector = item_code(i);
  if(pr_id == id_selector) {
  var p_title = $(this).find("product_title").text();
  var p_category = $(this).find("product_category").text();
  var p_code = $(this).find("product_code").text();
  var p_img = $(this).find("product_img").text();
  var p_url = $(this).find("product_url").text();



      $('a.anchor:lt(' + i + ')').attr('href', p_url);
      $('a.anchor:lt(' + i + ' img').attr('src', p_img);
      $('a.anchor:lt(' + i + ' h2').text(p_title);
      alert("XML ID: " + pr_id + " Title: " + p_title + "Category: " + p_category + " CODE: " + p_code + "IMG: " + p_img + " URL: " + p_url);
      }
      }

    });




},  
    error: function(){alert("Error: Something went wrong");}

  });

};
</script>
```

## The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<items xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <item>
        <p_id>1a</p_id>
        <product_title>Vitamin A</product_title>
        <product_category>Chemical</product_category>
        <product_code>ABCD</product_code>
        <product_img>img_10_vitamin_a.png</product_img>
        <product_url>10_vitamin_a.html</product_url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <p_id>1b</p_id>
        <product_title>Vitamin B</product_title>
        <product_category>Plants</product_category>
        <product_code>ASDF, 8820, 3423</product_code>
        <product_img>img_10_vitamin_b.png</product_img>
        <product_url>10_vitamin_b.html</product_url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <p_id>2a</p_id>
        <product_title>Vitamin C</product_title>
        <product_category>Chemical</product_category>
        <product_code>4503, 1111</product_code>
        <product_img>img_10_vitamin_c.png</product_img>
        <product_url>10_vitamin_c.html</product_url>
    </item>
    </items>
```

Condensed XML for easy of use is as follows:

```
var xml="<items><item><p_id>1a</p_id><product_title>Vitamin A</product_title><product_category>Chemical</product_category><product_code>ABCD</product_code><product_img>img_10_vitamin_a.png</product_img><product_url>10_vitamin_a.html</product_url></item><item><p_id>1b</p_id><product_title>Vitamin B</product_title><product_category>Plants</product_category><product_code>ASDF, 8820, 3423</product_code><product_img>img_10_vitamin_b.png</product_img><product_url>10_vitamin_b.html</product_url></item><item><p_id>2a</p_id><product_title>Vitamin C</product_title><product_category>Chemical</product_category><product_code>4503, 1111</product_code><product_img>img_10_vitamin_c.png</product_img><product_url>10_vitamin_c.html</product_url></item></items>";
```

I need to take the value from the `data-prd_id` attribute, and in the jquery, I need to search for that value in the xml. If found, I need to change the attributes and values of the respective div with the values taken from the xml. Currently, the product_category & product_code are not required, but I just needed to understand it too for knowledge purposes...

Thanks for any help.
Regards,

-

Comment: In your for loop you have `int i=1`. Should be `var i = 1`. Or just `i =1` will do.

Comment: Yes! That did the trick! But now I'm only getting the first item for the 3 divs... ie, only the `Vitamin A` is being replaced... all the divs are showing `vitamin A` from the xml... I tried adding `var` to `fValue`, but that also returned `Vitamin A` only..

Comment: Should it not also be `i < 3`

Comment: Well I changed that as well (`i < 3`) ... but still the div's are being replaced by the first anchor values only (`p_id=1a`)... I think this line of code is incorrect: `var fValue =  $('a.anchor:lt(' + j + ')').attr("data-prd_id");` .. It's getting the values correct, but for only the first id, not the remaining two  anchors... Please could you suggest a way to alter this? Should I use `div.h a.anchor:lt(j)....` for that line?

Comment: I solved it! Removed the for loop, if statement, and fValue.... then just used the custom attribute selector and it worked!! `$("a[data-prd_id='" + pr_id + "'] img").attr('src', p_img);`